# How to get just the responsive grid from Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to add responsive design features to my web application using Twitter Bootstrap. I just want the responsive behavior, I'm not interested in the typography, components or any other stuff included in Bootstrap.

I got a [customized Bootstrap version](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) just selecting the grid system. However, when I add the generated CSS to my application, all my styles are messed up (header, links and others). Why is that happening? How can I get a Bootstrap CSS with just the grid system? I would like to avoid a manual modification of the Bootstrap files.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and toggle just what you want from the BS3 framework and then click "Compile and Download" and you'll get the CSS and JS that you chose.

[image: Bootstrap Customizer]

Open up the CSS and remove all but the grid. They include some normalize stuff too. And you'll need to adjust all the styles on your site to box-sizing: border-box - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Thanks Christina. I was expecting there was a way to get just the grid styles.

Comment: Nope, they also download the supporting stuff, normalize and the scaffolding.less (which has the global border-box) which requires you to adjust all things that have padding. Such as before your box had 10px padding and the total was 200px, but the inside was 180px so you had to set the width to 180px, now you set the width to 200px or just nothing and stick it in a grid column class.

Comment: `box-sizing` reset info: http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/  & http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: still that has normalize.css

Comment: @rab -- that's mentioned in the answer. Remove it if you want, but it's useful.

Comment: Is there a way to get the SASS files customised?

Comment: @rab normalize.css is For improved cross-browser rendering,  source http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 20):

Checkout [zirafa/bootstrap-grid-only](https://github.com/zirafa/bootstrap-grid-only). It contains only the **bootstrap grid** and **responsive utilities** that you need (no reset or anything), and simplifies the **complexity** of working directly with the **LESS files**.

Comment: I quote from this GIT's description: What's not included: Pretty much everything else. It's really up to you. No styles, no javascript - not even a CSS reset.

Answer (score 9):

Just choose `Grid system` and "responsive utilities"
it gives you this: http://jsfiddle.net/7LVzs/

Answer (score 4):

Made a Grunt build with the Bootstrap 3.3.5 grid only:

https://github.com/horgen/grunt-builds/tree/master/bootstrap-grid

~10KB minimized.

If you need some other parts from Bootstrap just include them in /src/less/bootstrap.less.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using MDO's http://getpreboot.com/ instead. As of v2, `preboot` back ports the LESS mixins/variables used to create the Bootstrap 3.0 Grid System and is much more light weight than using the CSS generator. In fact, if you only include `preboot.less` there is NO overhead because the entire file is made up of mixins/variables and therefore are only used in pre-compilation and not the final output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can download just the grid now on Bootstrap 4s new download features.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but maybe now you can forego Bootstrap altogether and use CSS Grid! (it's simpler, neater, more flexible and faster). See this cool article: [Stop using Bootstrap — create a practical CSS Grid template for your component based UI](https://itnext.io/stop-using-bootstrap-create-a-practical-css-grid-template-for-your-component-based-ui-da784d974cc7?source=friends_link&sk=781ef46f3fb596cf86e0371cda6c0712)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, there are already separated files in their GitHub. You can find them here

```
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/main/dist/css
```